# Sum up values when keys in both files

Tags: awk

I have two files:

```
f1:
key1 value1
key2 value2 ...

f2:
key1 value1
key3 value2 ...
```

Now I want to get the sum of value, only for keys in both f1 and f2. How to do this in cmd line using awk or sed?

Comment: Always try to select any of the answers as a correct answer to complete the threads, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in a){print $2+a[$1]}' Input_file1  Input_file2
```